# Read unchecked mail in gmail and search for specific string with Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, unchecked

How can I log in an read unchecked emails from gmail with Python? Also great if I could search the body for a specific string.

I've gotten to this point:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('blah@gmail.com', 'password')
body = "jag fixar det"
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

typ, data = mail.search(None,'(UNSEEN BODY "%s")' % body)
print(data)
```

The return data i get is this: [b'5'] can someone explain what it means?

Comment: What code have you tried? What errors did you get?

Comment: yep updated, sorry for that.

Comment: What does `typ` return? I'd guess, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-objects) that you have 5 messages matching your [search criteria](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search)

Comment: I want my search criteria to be the string "jag fixar det" in the body of an email. Ive sent myself 1 email with excatly that. But it still returns 5... I think i might be on the wrong somewhere.